# Set limit_req for specific location in Nginx Ingress

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I'm trying to setup rate limiting option `limit_req` for specific path in Kubernetes ingress-nginx to prevent brute-forcing authentication.

I've defined `limit_req_zone` using ConfigMap:

```
http-snippet: |
      limit_req_zone $the_real_ip zone=authentication_ratelimit:10m rate=1r/s;
```

Next, I'm using annotation to add a custom location block:

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
  location ~* "^/authenticate$" {
    limit_req zone=authentication_ratelimit nodelay;
    more_set_headers "x-test: matched";
  }
```

This produces nginx.conf:

```
server {
# - - 8< - -

  location / {
    # - - 8< - -

    location ~* "^/authenticate$" {
      limit_req zone=authentication_ratelimit nodelay;
      more_set_headers "x-test: matched";
    }

    proxy_pass http://upstream_balancer;

    proxy_redirect                          off;
}
```

The result is that `/authenticate` always returns HTTP 503 (with x-test header). Message from ingress access logs:

```
<ip> - [<ip>] - - [04/Jan/2019:15:22:07 +0000] "POST /authenticate HTTP/2.0" 503 197 "-" "curl/7.54.0" 172 0.000 [-] - - - - 1a63c9825c9795be1378b2547e29992d
```

I suspect this might be because of conflict between nested location block and `proxy_pass` (but this is just a wild guess).

What other options have I tried?

- use `server-snippet` annotation instead of `configuration-snippet` - `/authenticate` returns 404 because `proxy_pass` is not configured
- use `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/limit-rpm` annotation - forces ratelimit on whole application which is not what I want.

Question is why custom location block responds with 503? How can I debug this? Will increasing nginx logging level give more details about 503?
Or more general question: can I inject custom location blocks in ingress-nginx?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This can be done by using map and that fact that [Requests with an empty key value are not accounted.](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_limit_req_module.html#limit_req_zone)

```
http-snippets: |
  map $uri $with_limit_req {
    default 0;
    "~*^/authenticate$" 1;
  }
  map $with_limit_req $auth_limit_req_key {
    default '';
    '1'     $binary_remote_addr; # the limit key
  }
  limit_req_zone $auth_limit_req_key zone=authentication_ratelimit:10m rate=1r/s;
```

And use annotation to add a custom location block:

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
  limit_req zone=authentication_ratelimit nodelay;
```

Or if you use ingress from nginxinc

```
nginx.org/location-snippets:
  limit_req zone=authentication_ratelimit nodelay;
```

in this case check if requests need to be ratelimited processed on map level.

And my opinion: better to limit requests on app level as if you made rate limit on ingress level, it depends on count of ingress pods.

Comment: I'm getting `nginx: [emerg] zero size shared memory zone "authentication_ratelimit"`. Any idea?

Comment: It looks like you have not defined `limit_req_zone`